# Is there a way to split a gl line once it is the shader?

Tags: glsl, webgl, mercator

I have a view where I can display the Earth, and satellites in a 3d view, or 2d view (Mercator). I can send the XYZ data to the shader, and the shader will do the appropriate display for 3d or 2d. In 2d, it does an XYZ to Lat/Lon/Alt conversion in the shader. The problem is as follows: In the 3d view, everything is great:

[image: 3d View]

The 2d view looks good, except for lines that in 3d cross the +/- 180 longitude boundary. The line is of course across the entire earth. What would be better, is if I could break the line into 2 segments (the proposed yellow lines below)
[image: 2d View]

I can't really fix this in the vertex shader, because I only have a single vertex to work with. All options I have come up with are ugly:

1. Move LLA conversion to CPU instead of GPU, and split lines there. (Waste of CPU, and doubling of data)
2. Multiply all vertices to have "phantom segments" to add segments, and turn segments on/off by changing transparency (up to 4x times the data to the vertex shader, and lots of extra transparent lines to the fragment shader).

Final limitation:  This is webgl, so I can't have a geometry shader.

Does anyone have some shader magic or cleverness so that I can keep this on the GPU?

Comment: Two ideas: 1. Find the edge cases manually on the CPU and render these separately 2. Take the 3D render, but project the blue lines onto the sphere, then render these to textures 6 times with different camera positions for a cube map, then use the cube map to render the Mercator projection.

Comment: It would be wrong to use simple lines in 2d rendering. In general, 3d geodesic line cannot be expressed by a straight line on 2d map. So, you need to divide lines into small segments to handle non-linear interpolations properly (=drawing curves). Then, if you implement this, the wrapping problem can be easily solved by just dropping a few segments that do cross the boundaries.

Comment: If the LLA conversion is done in the GPU and the shader only receives 3D points, then the lines must be rendered by some ray tracing algorithm, is that correct?

Comment: I understand that the *likely* answer is that it must be done as a computation in LLA on the CPU. I was hoping there was some non-obvious shader technique that might allow me to use the XYZ data in the GPU for faster processing. 
Yun's idea #1 is what I am trying to avoid (but I might have to do anyway.
Yun's idea #2 sounds interesting, and might mean less code, but more CPU that just splitting LLA.
Ardget is just re-expressing my problem.
Nikolay - I can render the lines with a fairly simple XYZ->LLA conversion. It's just that the border cases look bad (going over the 180W to 180E bound).